# Routing 6to4 packets through NAT

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, ipv6, 6to4

I have a linux router(dd-wrt w/o ipv6 module, no space for that) and a linux PC(Arch linux). I'm trying to setup my router to forward 6to4 packets(protocol 41) to my PC and setup the tunnel on it.

What I've done so far on router is:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p 41 -d ! 192.168.1.0/24 -j SNAT --to _WANIP_
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p 41 --dst _WANIP_ -j DNAT --to-destination _LANDEST_
```

where `_WANIP_` is my 'outside' ipv4 address and `_LANDEST_` is computer with 6to4 setup.
The 6to4 setup is done like that:

```
export IPV4_ADDRESS=_WANIP_
export OUR_IPV6_GW=`printf "2002:%02x%02x:%02x%02x::1" \`echo $IPV4_ADDRESS | tr '.' ' '\``
ip tunnel add tun6to4 mode sit ttl 32 remote any local $IPV4_ADDRESS
ip link set dev tun6to4 up
ip -6 addr add $OUR_IPV6_GW/16 dev tun6to4
ip -6 route add 2000::/3 via ::192.88.99.1 dev tun6to4 metric 1
```

`OUR_IPV6_GW` contains one of 6to4 addresses. After doing all this steps for test I do `ping6 ipv6.google.com` to see if the setup works and I get error messages `Destination unreachable: Address unreachable`

I can ping(IPv4) to 192.88.99.1, `ip -6 route` looks fine. I've also tried running `iptables -I [...]` for NAT setup to be sure that no rule shadows inserted ones.

I used some resources from http://www.wtfm.org/ip6to4

Comment: If you don't have enough space for the ipv6 module, your router must truly be ancient. Go find €25 and buy a new one.

Comment: @Michael Hampton, I'm working on that. I'll be switching to way better router with RouterOS L4.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use 6to4 through NAT. The IPv6 addresses depend on the public IPv4 address, which your 6to4 box doesn't have.

Besides, 6to4 is a obsolete/deprecated protocol. If you want IPv6 connectivity and your ISP doesn't provide it then you're better off using a managed 6in4 tunnel to e.g. Hurricane Electric our SixXS.

Comment: The idea was to configure the NAT in way that 6to4 packets are passed to/from 6to4 PC, so that's not the case I guess. Also it's nice to know about deprecation of the mechanism which was proposed quite recently( https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-v6ops-6to4-to-historic-11 ).

Comment: You can forward protocol 41 packets through NAT. The problem is that the inside box doesn't have the public address so the standard 6to4 doesn't work there. You'd have to trick it into using a public address that it doesn't have. Considering the low reliability of 6to4 you're better off with a managed tunnel.